# Notification feed issue with data structure of @activities, not sure how to loop through it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getstream-io

I'm trying to render my notification feed activities but I can't seem to figure out how to properly loop through `@activities`.

For background, I followed the recommended Sitepoint tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/super-easy-activity-feeds-with-stream/

My code is basically the same as that. Here's the `@activities` object:

```
[2] pry(#<FeedsController>)> @activities
=> [{"activities"=>
   [{"actor"=>
      #<User id: 1, email: "andy@dev.to", created_at: "2017-06-08-21:33:00", updated_at: "2017-06-13 18:15:59", name: "Andy">,
     "foreign_id"=>"Follow:4",
     "id"=>"861b2600-5063-11e7-8080-8000262131d5",
     "object"=>
      #<User id: 1, email: "andy@dev.to", created_at: "2017-06-08 21:33:00", updated_at: "2017-06-13 18:15:59", name: "Andy">,
     "origin"=>nil,
     "target"=>nil,
     "time"=>"2017-06-13T18:10:04.000000",
     "to"=>["notification:1"],
     "verb"=>"Follow"}],
  "activity_count"=>1,
  "actor_count"=>1,
  "created_at"=>"2017-06-13T18:10:04.000000",
  "group"=>"48946_2017-06-13",
  "id"=>"861b2600-5063-11e7-8080-8000262131d5",
  "is_read"=>false,
  "is_seen"=>false,
  "updated_at"=>"2017-06-13T18:10:04.000000",
  "verb"=>"Follow"},
 {"activities"=>
   [{"actor"=>
      #<User id: 1, email: "andy@dev.to", created_at: "2017-06-08 21:33:00", updated_at: "2017-06-13 18:15:59", name: "Andy">,
     "foreign_id"=>"Follow:1",
     "id"=>"8b249a80-4fbb-11e7-8080-80002a2ebc3f",
     "object"=>
      #<User id: 1, email: "andy@dev.to", created_at: "2017-06-08 21:33:00", updated_at: "2017-06-13 18:15:59", name: "Andy">,
     "origin"=>nil,
     "target"=>nil,
     "time"=>"2017-06-12T22:07:37.000000",
     "to"=>["notification:1"],
     "verb"=>"Follow"},
    {"actor"=>
      #<User id: 2, email: "niko@dev.to", created_at: "2017-06-08 21:35:33", updated_at: "2017-06-08 22:01:50", name: "Niko">,
     "foreign_id"=>"Follow:2",
     "id"=>"40edea00-4fb8-11e7-8080-8000106d4b0d",
     "object"=>
      #<User id: 1, email: "andy@dev.to", created_at: "2017-06-08 21:33:00", updated_at: "2017-06-13 18:15:59", name: "Andy">,
     "origin"=>nil,
     "target"=>nil,
     "time"=>"2017-06-12T21:44:04.000000",
     "to"=>["notification:1"],
     "verb"=>"Follow"}],
  "activity_count"=>2,
  "actor_count"=>2,
  "created_at"=>"2017-06-12T21:44:04.000000",
  "group"=>"48946_2017-06-12",
  "id"=>"8b249a80-4fbb-11e7-8080-80002a2ebc3f",
  "is_read"=>false,
  "is_seen"=>false,
  "updated_at"=>"2017-06-12T22:07:37.000000",
  "verb"=>"Follow"}]
```

Here's the main view (view/feeds/notification.html.erb):

```
<div class="page-header"><h1>Your notification feed</h1></div>

<% for activity in @activities %>

  <%= render_activity activity %>
<% end %>
```

And my partial (views/aggregated_activity/_follow.html.erb):

```
<div class="well well-sm">
  <p><small class="text-muted"><%= time_ago_in_words activity['time'] -%> ago</small></p>

  <p><strong><%= activity['object'].name %></strong> and <strong><%= activity['actor'].name %></strong> are now friends</p>
</div>
```

I can access the right object if I changed the above partial to the following:

```
<div class="well well-sm">
  <p><small class="text-muted"><%= time_ago_in_words activity['activities'][0]['time'] %> ago</small></p>

  <p><strong><%= activity['activities'][0]['object'].name %></strong> and <strong><%= activity['activities'][0]['actor'].name %></strong> are now friends</p>
</div>
```

However that doesn't seem like the right way to go about it. It also seems like the only activities shown are the instances where I'm following myself, and not when I follow the second user (John). What's the best way to loop into this array of hashes, whose values are arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to double check how current that sitepoint.com tutorial is, as we (Stream) didn't write it.

Back to your question, though: our notification feed, as you can see, ends up being grouped differently and you'd need a double loop for notification feeds:

```
<% for group in activities %>
  <% for activity in group %>
    <%= render_activity activity %>
```

As a side note, our [stream_rails](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails) library, has some [enrichment](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails#activity-enrichment) tools you can use to turn references in your activities back into full objects. By default it handles actor and object, which is what gives you access to things like `activity['actor'].name` that you see when dumping the activity data above, but you can also reference other models for metadata items if you were to include those later.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response; apologies for getting back to it late.

The tutorial is fairly old; it was published on October 1st, 2015. I'm sure things have changed since then.

As for the problem itself I think I was simply misunderstanding the return value... After creating a third user (Bob) to follow Andy, the notifications feed let me know Bob followed Andy. As for the 'Andy is now following Andy', I think that was just an issue of figuring out which notifications to display. Thanks again! You might be seeing more questions from me as I use Stream more though haha

Comment: Also I ended up using the original for loop you have on the readme: `<% for activity in @activities %> etc` and that worked out just fine. Again, just me misunderstanding what was happening with the data